# VXML :: Difference between bridged and consultation transfer

Tags: ivr, vxml, voicexml

From the VXML 2.1 documentation on Consultation

[Consultation_Transfer](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/#sec-transfer)

and from the documentation of VXML 2.0 on Bridged Transfer

[Briged transfer](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml2.3.7.2)

The only difference that i understand is this

- The platform maintains the session during the duration of the call even after transferring in Bridged transfer, where as in consultation transfer  it throws **connection.disconnect.transfer** upon the successful transfer.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually three types of transfers in VXML. You forgot to mention a blind transfer. A blind transfer terminates the application as soon as the transfer is initiated. A consultation transfer is like a blind transfer except that it makes sure that the transfer completes before terminating the application. If the transfer does not complete successfully then it returns to the application.  A bridged transfer on the other hand keeps the application running after the transfer has completed. For a bridged transfer you can consider the two parties and the IVR application being conferenced together.

You want to check your IVR vendor on how they implemented the transfer for any details.  Not all IVR vendors are the same in how they implemented the spec. Many do not support the consultation transfer at all, only allowing bridged or blind transfers.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph.  You should check with both your IVR vendor _and_ your PBX/ACD vendor, as call transfer and interaction with IVRs often have specific characteristics that will impact other applications.  For example, some PBX implementations use a call identifier that changes as different equipment handles a call.  You'll have a caller enter your PBX with one ID, enter your IVR with a different one, and then transfer out with a third, different, ID!

Answer (score 0):

Consultation transfer uses some kind of supervised transfer, before making transfer it analyses the status of destination like busy/ or free, then transfers call. 
Bridged transfer will use conference kind of thing, it uses third line, say a caller is on call with IVR, if the call needs to transferred to an agent, IVR will use a third free channel allocated to IVR, then connects to agent, actually these four channels are used for two calls. 
now "Bridge" term derived from connecting these two calls like conference.
So, all these four channels utilized till end of conversation with agent

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Party A calls party B (could be IVR or human). Party B wants to transfer to Party C.

**Consult Transfer:** Party B initiates the transfer but monitors for Party B to answer before completing the transfer and hanging up. after that, Party A and C continue on the call alone.

**Bridge Transfer:** Party B initiates the transfer but monitors for Party B to answer before completing the transfer but it stays on the call in suspended
mode. When Party C hangs up, Party B re-engages with Party A. Think of IVR application (i.e. party B) taking the call back to a Customer Survey application after finishing the call with the Agent (i.e. party C).

**Blind Transfer:** Party B transfers the call to Party C and doesnt care whether or not party C answers, available or hangs up the call.

check this page which provides a good explanation:
https://www.devconnectprogram.com/forums/posts/list/17727.page